# Google PageSpeed compressing and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching, optimization

I am trying to speed up my website as best as I can. I ran Google's PageSpeed, got 83/100.

Page says to compress resources, such as .js and .css files.

"Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can reduce the number of bytes sent over the network."

Okey, then I googled and edited my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js|xml)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
    Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType image/png A604800
  ExpiresByType image/gif A604800
  ExpiresByType image/jpg A604800
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg A604800
  ExpiresByType text/javascript A604800
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A604800
  ExpiresByType text/css A604800
</IfModule>
```

When I inspect my site:

Headers:

```
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
```

Cache:

```
Data Size   332
Device  disk
Expires Thu Jan 01 1970 02:00:00
```

And PHP in my site:

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip'))
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); 
else 
    ob_start();
header('Vary: Accept');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=28800');
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Don't compress the output in PHP, let Apache handle all of it.  Is `mod_deflate` installed and enabled?

Comment: Removed PHP output. mod_deflate is enabled.
This site says that my site is gzipped: http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test
How ever, PageSpeed still says "Compressing resources with gzip or deflate can reduce the number of bytes sent over the network."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample code above there's no extension specified for html content e.g. .php

I generally manage gzip by mimetype rather than by file extension e.g.

```
  <IfModule mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml \ 
    etc
```

See https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess for a full list.